# Colorpicker doesn't work

Tags: liferay, yui, liferay-6, color-picker

i use Liferay 6.1, I created a portlet with code (Link: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Lifery+provided+Color+Picker+in+Own+Portlets)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery( function() { var colorPicker = new Liferay.ColorPicker( { hasImage: true } ); } ); </script>


<tr> <td> <input class="text-input" id="color" name="color" size="9" type="text" value="" />

<img align="absmiddle" alt="<liferay-ui:message key="color" />" border="0" class="use-color-picker" height="18" hspace="0" src="<%= themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages() %>/color.png" title="<liferay-ui:message key="color" />" vspace="0" width="18" style="cursor: pointer;" />

</input> </td> </tr>
```

but it doesn't work, please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass more options to `new Liferay.ColorPicker` . According to the guide you posted:

> Options:
>
> •context (Object): A DOM object which specifies the context in which
>   to search for the item 
>   •hasImage: (Boolean) If set to true, it uses
>   the "item" param or whatever image has the .use-color-picker class as
>   the image  
>   •item: (Object|String): A DOM object or a jQuery Selector
>   string that specifies which field to insert the selected value into 
>  
>   •onChange (Function): A function that will get called whenever the
>   color changes 
>   •onClose (Function): A function that will get called
>   when the color picker is closed.

Comment: hi Stijin, i think above code will display colorpicker, but it only show inputtext and image, not show color picker,i need to pass more options ?

Comment: hi Stijin, code for liferay 6.0 work(link: http://usefulliferaytips.blogspot.com/2012/11/color-picker-in-liferay.html) :)
but i don't know why above code not work like wiki :|

Comment: That link says you have to use AUI to make it work. The code you posted doesn't use AUI...